# Timber Pagination issues with custom post type in drafts

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

**Explanation :**

I made a search form on my custom post type archive.php that working as expected for standard users using Timber (and Bedrock).

Now, I want for user with at least the role author to display all post in publish or draft status. The idea It's to allow author and other user working on the site to see how the post rendered in the list view.

However, the draft posts are not counted by wordpress or timber as expected. What I'm meaning, I have 5 posts published and 1 in draft and I set up my wordpress setting in order to display 1 post per page.

As a non author I will be able to go from page 1 to page 6 without any issue. But as author, editor or other higher role I should be able to go from page 1 to page 7... and at the 6th page  I'm able to go to the "next page" thanks to Timber pagination but when I'm click on it the 7th page is a 404 error page...

**What I'm expecting :**
I'm expecting to be able to go to the last page.

**My code :**
My archive-post_type.php is like:

```php
<?php
use \Timber\Timber;

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect(home_url().'/login');
    exit();
}
global $paged;
if (!isset($paged) || !$paged) {
    $paged = 1;
}
$context = Timber::context();
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$isSubscriber=$user->roles[0]=="subscriber"?true:false;
if (isset($_REQUEST["entity"])) {
    $search = isset($_REQUEST["searchName"])?$_REQUEST["searchName"]:"";
    $searchContain = $_REQUEST["searchType"]==="contain"?true:false;
    $args=Search('form', $isSubscriber, $searchContain, $search, $paged);
} else {
    $search = "";
    $searchContain = true;
    $args=Search('form', $isSubscriber, $searchContain, $search, $paged);
}

$context['posts']= new \Timber\PostQuery($args);
\Timber\Timber::render('form/list.twig', $context);


function Search($post_type, $isSubscriber, $searchContain, $search, $paged)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "
        SELECT *
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
        WHERE post_type = '" . $post_type . "'"
    ;

    if ($isSubscriber) {
        $query .= " AND post_status = 'publish'";
        $post_status="publish";
    } else {
        $post_status="any";
    }
    if (!empty($search)) {
        if ($searchContain) {
            $query .= " AND post_title LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
        } else {
            $query .= " AND post_title LIKE '" . $search . "%'";
        }
    }
    $results=$wpdb->get_results($query);

    if (!empty($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $posts[] = $result->ID;
        }
        return $args = [
            'post__in'          => $posts,
            'post_type'         => $post_type,
            'post_status'       => $post_status,
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'orderby'           => 'title',
            'posts_per_page'    => get_option('posts_per_page'),
            'paged'             => $paged
        ];
    }
    return [];
}
```

My list.twig :

```html
{% extends 'layout/base.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <nav class="breadcrumb">
        {{ breadcrumb() }}
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="list-title">
                <h1>Form list</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="list-search">
                <form id="search" method="GET" action="{{ site.link }}/form" class="form">
                    <select class="search-type" name="searchType" form="search">
                        <option selected value="contain">Contain</option>
                        <option value="start">Start with</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="search" class="search-field" name="searchName" placeholder="Search">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="dynamic_search">
                    <input type="hidden" name="entity" value="for">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
                {% if posts is not empty %}
                    {% for i, post in posts %}
                        {% set description = post.meta('form-description') %}
                        {% set shortcode = post.meta('form-shortcode') %}
                        {% if shortcode is not empty %}
                            <div class="list-item__body list-item-form item-{{ i }} {% if post.post_status != "publish" %}not-publish{% endif %}">
                                {% if post.post_status != "publish" %}
                                    <div class="ribbon ribbon-top-right"><span>Draft</span></div>
                                {% endif %}
                                <div class="list-item__title">
                                    <a href="{{ url }}./{{ post.slug }}">
                                        <h2>{{ post.post_title }}</h2>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="list-item__description">
                                    {{ description |raw | truncate(15,true, ' ...')}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="list-item__more">
                                    <a href="{{ url }}./{{ post.slug }}">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <p>Forms not found</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-pagination">
            {% if posts.pagination.prev %}
                <div class="list-pagination__action list-pagination__prev">
                    <i class="left fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                    <a href="{{posts.pagination.prev.link}}" class="next {{posts.pagination.prev.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Previous page</a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if posts.pagination.next %}
                <div class="list-pagination__action list-pagination__next">
                    <a href="{{posts.pagination.next.link}}" class="next {{posts.pagination.next.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Next page</a>
                    <i class="right fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Note: I followed the *What if I’m not using the default query?*
 explanation part of Timber pagination guide: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/pagination/

Comment: Is there a reason you build a custom SELECT instead of working with parameters for `WP_Query` / `Timber\PostQuery`?

Comment: It is, I wasn't able to make a post title research with  ```Timber\PostQuery```.